# log4j2 multiple files created

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

I'm trying to config my logger with such log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile"  append="true" fileName="logger1"
                              filePattern="logger1_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">     
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%tid] [%X{id}] %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p - %m%n"/>
        <Policies>              
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
         </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile2" append="true" fileName="logger2"   
                             filePattern="logger2_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">      
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%tid] [%X{id}] %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p - %m%n"/>
        <Policies>              
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
         </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
    <Console name="IDE-Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%tid] [%X{id}] %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="logger1" level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="logger2" level="info" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile2"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="info" >
      <AppenderRef ref="IDE-Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And the problem is in creation of two files when, I think, it is supposed to be the one.

Actually, after I invoke

```
LoggerContext.getContext(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), false, file.toURI());
```

log4j2 creates two files: logger{1,2}

Then I can get proper logger by name and start logging to a proper file, having one extra file empty which I don't want to be created in my application folder.
It actually restricts me to distribute this file to all my application where only one logger needed. I thought using

```
getLogger(String loggerName)
```

you can manage the file you write to.

Any ideas how to fix it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

File Appenders will always create the file when Log4j initializes. So if you configure two file appenders you will get two files. The behavior you are seeing is the expected behavior.

It is possible to dynamically create log files on demand with the RoutingAppender. This requires that your application uses the ThreadContext. The faq page has an example configuration that shows how to do this: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#separate_log_files